# Pandas : how to consider content of certain columns as list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a simple pandas dataframe named df :

```
   0          1
0  a  [b, c, d]
```

I save this dataframe into a CSV file as follow :

```
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")
```

Then later in my script I read this csv :

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=False, sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")
```

Now what I want to do is to use explode() on column '1' but it does not work because the content of column '1' is not a list since I saved df into a CSV file.

What I tried so far is to change column '1' type into a list with astype() without any success.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: I guess you need to use `ast.literal_eval` after reading from csv since, pandas doesn't infer list type you would get them as a string.

Comment: You can consider using a file that can serialize python objects, like `.pkl` for instance (`df.to_pickle()`)

Comment: @Ch3steR This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Since you are reading from csv file,your dataframe value in column `A` (`1` in your case) is essentially a string for which you need to infer the values as list.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":["['a','b']","['c']"],"B":[1,2]})
df["A"]=df["A"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Now, the following works !

```
df.explode("A")
```